# SharedPreferences value does not stick

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am trying to save a string to `SharedPerferences` like this:

**Write**

```
var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences ("Janssen", FileCreationMode.WorldReadable);  

var prefEditor = prefs.Edit ();
prefEditor.PutString ("SecurityToken", SecurityCode.Text);
prefEditor.Commit ();
```

**Read**

```
var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences ("Janssen", FileCreationMode.WorldReadable);  

var SecurityToken = prefs.GetString ("SecurityToken", null);
```

I am new to Android coming from iOS. I am trying to emulate `NSUserDefaults` in iOS. I am reading the `SharedPreferences` in a new activity, maybe that is what causes the problem? I am not sure. I also have no idea what to set as default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you re-deploying between writing your `SharedPreferences` and reading them? This often wipes the `SharedPreferences`.

I have just tested them and they work fine between two `Activities`:

*WritePrefsAcitivity.cs*

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Derrrp
{
    [Activity (Label = "Derrrp", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class WritePrefsActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Write);

            var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefs", FileCreationMode.Private);
            var prefsEditor = prefs.Edit();

            var ed = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
            ed.AfterTextChanged += (sender, e) => {
                prefsEditor.PutString("MyPref", e.Editable.ToString());
                prefsEditor.Commit();
            };

            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

            button.Click += delegate {
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(ReadPrefsActivity));
                StartActivity(intent);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

*ReadPrefsActivity.cs*

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Derrrp
{
    [Activity (Label = "ReadPrefsActivity")]            
    public class ReadPrefsActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Read);

            var tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.myTextView);
            var button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);

            var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefs", FileCreationMode.Private);

            button.Click += (sender, e) => {
                tv.Text = prefs.GetString("MyPref", "");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The `defValue` can be set to anything you want. This is the value that will be chosen if the preference you are trying to get is empty.

**NOTE**: If you are using it to store some secret information it is advised to use `FileCreationMode.Private` and even use something that makes it only readable by the application, such as encryption.

[image: GIF image showing the two activities working.]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the error you have, but below is an example i used before for saving a string using shared preferences. 
I used to set default value to "", so that while reading, if the value was not saved before, it will set the variable to empty string. You can read the shared preferences in any new activity , shared preferences is per application not activity ..

example:

writing string:

```
 String pass = "abcdefg";
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
 editor.putString("savedPass", pass);
 editor.commit();
```

reading string:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
 String mypassword = preferences.getString("savedPass", "");
```